# Passing variable through URL in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm facing some trouble to pass variables trough templates/URL/view in my index.html.

This is my URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('dma.urls')),
] 

app_name = 'root'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:category_id>', views.index, name='index'),
    path('buy/', views.buy, name='buy'),
    path('sell/', views.sell, name='sell'),
    path('stock/', views.stock, name='stock'),
    path('debtor/', views.debtor, name='debtor'),
    path('debtor/<str:buyer>', views.debt, name='debt'),
    path('financial/', views.financial, name='financial'),
]
```

My view:

```
def index(request, category_id):
    products = Buy.objects.filter(sell__buyer__isnull=True)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

My template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
 <a href="{% url 'root:index' category.id %}" class="list-group-item">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure but the problem might be in URL code. The template is printing exactly the categories names in the `{{ category.name }}`

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in home.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
users/
<int:category_id> [name='index']
buy/ [name='buy']
sell/ [name='sell']
stock/ [name='stock']
debtor/ [name='debtor']
debtor/<str:buyer> [name='debt']
financial/ [name='financial']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

EDIT -> maybe the problem is: the index can work without requesting the variable 'category_id'. In this way, should I have 2 URLs like these:

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:category_id>/', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: You are not making use of `category_id` in your views

Comment: Can you also add Category model here ?

Comment: @AstikAnand not yet, but I will. I was testing page just to make sure the code was Ok but I've been faced with the error.

Comment: Just for confirmation are these urls in one file?

Comment: No, there are two URLs files. The default is the first one in above explanation. The second one is inside the dma app, called 'root'.

Comment: can you try editing path to `path('', include('dma.urls', namespace='root')),`? and in views edit `category_id=None`

Comment: Both URL are working correctly with other templates. I'm having this new error because I'm trying to pass a variable through the index.html, otherwise, everything is working OK...

Comment: Ok, then you are using `'root:some_view'` at other places too?

Comment: @Hisham___Paky Yes, I am.

Comment: @FelipeDourado Is category.id a non-null value? Did you try using reverse function in the shell to ensure you're that URL is correct? `reverse('root:index', args=[10]) # for example`

Comment: @arthursribeiro I've just edited the question. Maybe the error is because sometimes I don't have the variable to get through the 'get method' - empty value of the variable category.id. So, in this way, when I first open the localhost, this variable is empty. But when the page was supposed to load for the first time, the user could be linked with its value to be used in views.index...

Comment: @FelipeDourado Still got the same error or it changed?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered what it was wrong. Two modifications:

URL (two paths for the same view -> index):

```
app_name = 'root'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:category_id>', views.index, name='index'),
```

VIEWS (set 'category_id' as a default value):

```
def index(request, category_id=''):
   products = Buy.objects.filter(sell__buyer__isnull=True)
   if category_id != '':
       products = products.filter(category=category_id)
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   context = {'products': products, 'categories': categories,
           'category_id': category_id}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Thank you for sharing different ideas!